# How to insert 'const Obj' into std::list<T*>?

Tags: c++, list, constants, containers, std

I wrote a function

```
    void addAnything(T const &obj)
    {
    ...
    m_list.push_front(obj); // - line returns C2664 - list is initialized by std::list<T*> m_list
     ...
    }
```

and my Problem is to convert from 'const T' in 'T *const'. And I need to insert it into this list... =/ Any method for inserting elements into a std::list requires 'const T& x'.
Is there any way to insert an const item into my list and keep the parameter of addAnything()?
Maybe by adapting m_list?

Thx for any advice!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Are you aware of std::list<T*> definition? Manually you should delete object when is removed from the list.
I not than replace std::list<T*> with std::list<T>.

Comment: "replace std::list with std::list" -- what do you mean with this?

Comment: @Sevis: read more exact: replacing std::list<Tstar> with std::list<T> - store the object instead of a pointer - correct?

Comment: @user903325: My comment was before the edit, which indeed clarifies the issue.  However, `std::list<T*>` and `std::list<T>` have very different semantics; they are not interchangeable in most cases.

Answer (score 2):

You have a `const` object, and you're trying to insert it into a container of non-`const` pointers to non-`const` objects.  I'm going to assume you meant to use `&obj`, but even then, this isn't going to work:  what if `obj` is a temporary?  You'll need to either make `obj` a `T&`, or make a copy of `obj` (probably with `new`) and push the address of that.

Note that when you have a container of `T*`, it is not always clear who owns the `T`s in it.  Unless you explicitly don't want the container to take ownership (in that case, pushing `new`ed things is a bad idea), you may want to use `boost::ptr_list<T>`.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
m_list.push_front(new T(obj));
```

Answer (score 1):

There are two problems with your code: first, you are pushing an object reference when the list expects a pointer; second, your list requires a non-const pointer. You can solve the second problem by either creating a copy of `obj` or changing the list's type to `std::list<const T*>`.

```
// 1.
m_list.push_front(new T(obj)); // don't forget to delete it later

// 2.
std::list<const T*> m_list;
m_list.push_front(&obj);
```

Note, that with the second method, you have to make sure that `obj` is valid for as long as you store a pointer to it in `m_list`.

Comment: Second one is not ok *cause holds a pointer to a deleted object) if passed object is stack allocated.

Comment: @dnikku: obviously, storing a pointer to a temporary object is a bad idea. This would not be a problem with my code, however.

Answer (score 0):

```
 m_list.push_front(obj); 
// - line returns C2664 - list is initialized by std::list<T*> m_list
```

Error message complains you that the `m_list` is of type `std::list<T*>`. Meaning, `m_list` can hold elements of type `T*`. But you are pushing `obj` which is of type `T&`. References are not pointers.

> Is there any way to insert an const item into my list and keep the parameter of addAnything()? Maybe by adapting m_list?

```
std::list<const T> m_list;
void addAnything( const T& obj ){
     m_list.push_front(obj);

     // ...

}
```